# Calling function inside another function globally Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, function

Good evening community, I would like you to help me with this logic problem about the functions in vanilla JS.

There is a global function, inside this i made several functions, I would like to know how to access each one independently of the input order.

I have created an example, am I following the right way?

```
var FEGlobal = {
  FEHomepage: {
    Init: function () {
      this.Cursor();
    },
    Cursor: function () {
      mouseOver();
      mouseOut();
    },
  },
  FEMedia: {
    Init: function () {
      this.MouseOver();
      this.MouseOut();
    },
    MouseOver: function () {},
    MouseOut: function () {},
  },
  BEGlobal: { Init: function () {} },
};
```

My idea is to make a custom mouseOver / mouseOut functions, what i need to use before they are defined. So in the Cursor function () i wish to call them inside that funcion.

```
Cursor: function () {
const projectOriginal = document.querySelectorAll("#project__original");
        projectOriginal.forEach((element) => {
          element.addEventListener("mouseover", function mouseOver() {}, false);
          element.addEventListener("mouseout", function mouseOut() {}, false);
        });
}
```

Comment: There are no functions defined inside of other functions in the code you’ve shown. What is the “input order”? Without knowing how this code is used or what the goal is, how do you expect us to determine whether this is _“following the right way”_?

Comment: @SebastianSimon excuse me, i should have described my question better. My idea is to make a custom mouseOver and mouseOut functions, what i need to use them before they are defined, so that's why i'm asking about using function inside another one.

Comment: @SebastianSimon i edited my post to show you, how i want to use them inside a function.

Comment: An expression like `function mouseOver() {}` defines a new function that does nothing; it doesn’t use an existing `mouseOver` function. Also, the name `mouseOver` can only be used inside this function. It’s still not quite clear how `FEGlobal` is used.

Comment: You call them like this: `FEGlbal.FEHomepage.Init()`

Comment: @SebastianSimon so i don't need a global variable which one takes all other functions, and then push them to DOM? excuse me for this undestanding.. idea is creating a custom functions and then work with them on every place at document